# Who Can I Hire To Calculate the Value of An Estate?

Tags: will, estate-settlement, russia

My grandfather in Russia recently died, and he was very private about the state of his finances and did not leave a will. Because of that, nobody, not even his son, really knows what he's worth. He owns three properties and was the head of a business, and it's unclear what he had in terms of bank accounts. Is there a specific person who can be hired to do the research on his affairs at death to determine what exactly the value of his estate is?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, it would be an accountant. Specifically in the case of very "private" (or unorganized, which is even worse) person - *forensic* accountant.

Since there's no will - it will probably require a lawyer as well to gain access to all the accounts the accountant discovers.

I would start with a **good** estate attorney, who in turn will hire a forensic accountant to trace the accounts.